# C: Segmentation fault while reading user input with fgets

Tags: c, input, fgets

I'm new to C and I'm trying to write a program with a lot of user input. For that purpose I wrote this function:

```
char * addValue(char * msg){
    char * input[80];
    printf("%s", msg);
    fflush(stdout);
    fgets(*input, 80, stdin);
    strtok(*input, "\n");
    return *input;
}
```

This function works perfectly in the whole program except in this part:

```
struct User{
    char userid[10];
    char email[80];
    char name[80];
    char password[80];
    char downloaded[10];
    char registred[10];
};

int change() {
    char * query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE user_id=";
    char * userid = addValue("Enter the User ID: "); // Works here
    // Here is a MySQL query
    char * email = addValue("Mail: "); // -> Segmentation Fault
    printf("%s\n", email);
    struct User usrvalues;
    strcpy(usrvalues.email, email);
    return 0;
}
```

I have absolutely no idea, why the second function call is not working. I have other functions in the program where I call the addValue() function multiple times without any errors.

When I debug this with gdb, I get this result:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff6445b77 in __GI__IO_getline_info () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
```

`bt` gives me the following informations:

```
#0  0x00007ffff6445b77 in __GI__IO_getline_info () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff6444a3d in fgets () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x000000000040142b in addValue ()
#3  0x00000000004016e9 in change ()
#4  0x0000000000401bd0 in main ()
```

I tried different inputs ("" (an empty string), different numbers like 100 and different strings like "test"), but it every time it ends with a segmentation fault.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have `char *input[80];` which is an array of 80 uninitialized pointers.  You probably want `char input[80];`, though I'm not convinced the line limit should be that short (you can only read 78-character lines, plus a newline, plus a null into it).  I tend to use numbers like 4096, partly for the shock value.  You could use 256 sanely.  You'll then need to fix the call to `fgets()` and `strtok()`. You also have to decide how you'll handle returning the data to the calling function; you can't simply return a pointer to a local array (it doesn't exist after the function returns).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input` is an *uninitialized* array of pointers. By doing `*input` you get the first *uninitialized* pointer and pass it to `fgets`.

I'm sure you didn't mean to create an array of pointers to `char`, but an array of `char`:

```
char input[80];
```

---

However, you have a more serious problem than that, because you then return a pointer to this local array `input` (well, after the change described above you would), and that leads to *undefined behavior* because local variables are local, they disappear when the function returns and will leave you with a stray pointer.

You have two solutions to this problem: The first is to declare the array in the calling function, and pass it (and its size) to the function, just like you pass `input` and its length to `fgets` now.

The second solution is to create the array dynamically using `malloc`, and then remember to `free` it once you're done with it.

Comment: Was writing my answer as yours showed up... deleting mine now.